# Installing numpy in virtualenv on raspbian

Tags: python, numpy, pip, virtualenv, raspberry-pi3

I'm running a raspberry pi3 and created a virtualenv. I'm using pip to install numpy. 
I'm following the steps shown in [this link](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/10/26/how-to-install-opencv-3-on-raspbian-jessie/)

I'm getting stuck with an error and not able to proceed, any ideas on a solution?

[Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/KcteWwKx) for the error

Comment: looks weird. did you try nuking the virtualenv and retrying the install